# Mysql 5.5 aggregate time intervals

Tags: mysql

I have seen plenty of posts about how to specify a time interval. I tried to use them but I get strange results.
This is my table:

```
select value,time from mysensor9 order by time desc;

+-------+---------------------+
| value | time                |
+-------+---------------------+
|    79 | 2016-01-27 22:19:46 |
|    45 | 2016-01-27 22:19:45 |
|     5 | 2016-01-27 22:19:44 |
|    72 | 2016-01-27 22:19:43 |
|    20 | 2016-01-27 22:19:42 |
|    92 | 2016-01-27 22:19:41 |
 .....
```

I have filled a table with values for every second of a month.

Then I try to aggregate the data of the table for every 5min/ hour/day/month. When I try to aggregate the average value per day I make this query:

```
select AVG(value),time from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (3600*24) order by time asc;
```

The results are ok:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| AVG(value) | time                |
+------------+---------------------+
|    48.7179 | 2015-12-09 02:13:46 |
|    49.4044 | 2015-12-10 02:13:46 |
|    49.5001 | 2015-12-11 02:13:46 |
|    49.4805 | 2015-12-12 02:13:46 |
|    48.9036 | 2015-12-13 02:13:46 |
```

When I want to aggregate per 1 hour interval I make this query:

```
select AVG(value),time from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (3600) order by time asc;
```

EDIT(hour interval results):

```
+------------+---------------------+
| AVG(value) | time                |
+------------+---------------------+
|    49.2355 | 2015-12-09 00:13:46 |
|    48.0028 | 2015-12-09 01:13:46 |
|    49.6316 | 2015-12-09 02:13:46 |
|    47.8449 | 2015-12-09 03:13:46 |
|    49.0166 | 2015-12-09 04:13:46
```

|

And again the results are ok. But when I want to aggregate 5 minute intervals using the same approach:

```
select AVG(value),time from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300) order by time asc;
```

I get this:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| AVG(value) | time                |
+------------+---------------------+
|    44.9865 | 2015-12-09 00:13:46 |
|    50.3310 | 2015-12-09 00:15:00 |
|    50.0135 | 2015-12-09 01:13:46 |
|    47.4843 | 2015-12-09 01:15:00 |
|    51.8514 | 2015-12-09 02:13:46 |
```

Why is this happening? Why it does not return something like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| AVG(value) | time                |
+------------+---------------------+
|    44.9865 | 2015-12-09 00:13:46 |
|    50.3310 | 2015-12-09 00:18:46 |
|    50.0135 | 2015-12-09 00:23:46 |
|    47.4843 | 2015-12-09 00:28:46 |
|    51.8514 | 2015-12-09 00:33:46 |
```

Comment: You would normally GROUP BY the same thing that you SELECT. So if you GROUP BY time/5 then you would SELECT time/5

Comment: Can you post what the hour interval query returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select something thats not part of the GROUP BY its pretty random what mysql selects for you (it will select any one of the grouped rows).

You should select the same value you grouped by and format it back to a date:

```
select AVG(value),DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300))*300),'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i:%s') as group_time from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300) order by time asc;
```

You also could use MIN() / MAX() to always get the upper or lower end of your grouped rows, if this is practical for your case it seems a bit more elegant:

```
select AVG(value),MIN(time) from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300) order by time asc;
```

Also note that selecting non group columns in a group by context is MySQL behaviour, some other Databases would simply state this as a syntax error.

Comment: It's not that random, mysql selects the 1st value it encounters while scanning the data in such cases (which is completely logical). Obviously, one should not rely on such undocumented features because they may change without any notice.

Comment: Well as you can not predict what that value will be, it seems pretty random - thats what i meant.

Comment: Since group by orders the resultset, you can actually guess it quite accurately :)

Comment: I have seen a lot of cases where it delivered conpletely other rows than one would have guessed. But i think we both agree on guessing being a bad idea :)

Comment: Hmm I used your 1st approach. It kinda messed my results even more:
+------------+---------------------+
| AVG(value) | group_time          |
+------------+---------------------+
|    44.9865 | 26-02-1970 12:14:02 |
|    50.3310 | 26-02-1970 12:14:03 |
|    50.0135 | 26-02-1970 12:14:14 |

Comment: Ah sorry - as we divided the timestamp by 300 we would have to multiply it back by 300 first (i updated the answer), but i would try the 2nd approach first :)

Answer (score 0):

`select AVG(value),UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300) from mysensor9 where time > "2015-12-09" group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) div (300) order by time asc;'`

you should use group like this.